# Precheck ascii 0-9 using an if-statement before switch for performance

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement, switch-statement, jump-table

I have two functions which both check if an input char is a number (along other characters), but they do it in different ways:

- `foo_precheck(char c)` first checks if the ascii code of char is in a certain range which denotes a number.
- `foo_switch(char c)` uses a jumptable with fallthrough cases from 0-9 to determine that a char is a number.

The question now is: which function is faster? I was curious if this would optimize to the same assembly under -O2, but it didn't:

[LiveDemo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgBykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAzBqkAA6oCoRODB7evgGp6ZkCoeFRLLHxSbaY9o4CQgRMxAQ5Pn5cgXaYDlkNTQQlkTFxickKjc2teR22EwNhQ%2BUjSQCUtqhexMjsHOYJYcjeWADUJgluyOP4qGfYJhoAgvcPAG6oeOjH/KgA%2BinE3QQ3QA1hBkAgmsdkCtniYAOxWR7HZHHPBUY5g04JO4JAAixw0qiSpzMADZzKSoVi3Gd8YSEgBOFanBHPFHs47/MIEKgQcxmADqTAUxyYxwYw2IYDAJgArG4GPyYQlEQ8OSiAQRNgwsar2fDcWyUQoAO6EcFg5nwvXqqHCzDHMC7BFOkBG9WiJSO3ayiyulk220ormCXn8gDyBCBxGO4y8VCo0rlCqVZ0DQeO0QBTGBafdHIN%2BfZWCoTC8tAIIEz2dzKvzhceDaejzeHy%2BqF%2BpvNCDBEJj0NhrKRxrNBAt0IDRZRnodTo0rqnyJn3q4C%2BHHvt3rMa7VtuXToSO6D%2B44kiPe83Ttl543XqdpJvHJPcMf7JP/lf08vHAZ/uti45EMeT5MxBWFUVxUlJN5UVUDlXTIMs0wHM83XAs4UNNC32/a1PyXHDfT/IddwzTliG5MNQMjaNYy1BNoJTODUJIjMkJQussJRJsgxLMsKyrNja3TJsRMbR40AYcZjjeAxHHoKE%2B2OGNaW9a9dg45sHm5Y4WCYMIIBhRtiPZb4/gBcEQQgYh4PzUyuzHHtrOYg0ODWWhOFlXg/A4LRSFQTgaUsaxYw2LYHT2HhSErHzXLWYEQFlSQADpSTMKQNAZBk0tJOEuA0Mx9E4SQvM0Xh/I4XgFBAZJoq0NY4FgGBEBQVAWBSOg4nISg0Dajr4kOQxgB%2BAhiC8BhgT4OgCDiKqIGiUrSGiMImgAT04SKerYQRwwYWg1pi0gsF0oxxAO/BzMcF5MCqg7MFUbovGmhbuRqBbaDwLNVo8LAFpGvAWHW1y%2BAMYAFAANTwTATXDFJGEBmRBBEMR2CkBH5CUNQFt0Lh9EGlBrGsfQPqqyA1lQFI6kkzgAFpqauWlTCCywuDhY5qfDMxKpqbpKZcBh3E8No9BCBYygqPQ0gySmpnaAopayQYxZGHGuh6eo5hlvRVcpvpmkVyUtY1wXplmfp9aWeIuDWBRQu2PQRswHYeDcjySoO8rVH8UlqdJSQoQMIwMRGsbgWZCBAqsSxSGOXBCBIEkEhx44PF6%2BhlLMROVl4WrYtIeLZWSdzT14AHJASJKEllOEElJSvJDMauGUkWVSG83zysq6qotK%2BqmogJANgIFJHq6sFWvatOIlYHZPe933/cGoPRvGrOgnwIhyPQPR%2BER0RxFRnf0ZUdQDux0gTWIJgUkBl2OE81uFvK8NHuHghjlQdFZ59v2BsDiBg5XhiFOE84gJyttnHuawgRMCwPEAyhVi6kABrKUkKV66119lXMkGhZQtzbmVTgncaqQLziAZuFc4T%2BFlAyDQGhKEJDMP4BkgQi4JDdu3Qh3cYorFvpzB%2B7tOE5x4aQK6xAMjOEkEAA%3D%3D)

```
#include <cstdio>

void foo_precheck(char c)
{
    if (c >= 0x30 && c <= 0x39) {
        printf("Was a number!\n");
        return ;
    }
    switch(c) {
        case '{':
        case '[': {
            printf("Other stuff!\n");
            break;
        }
        default: break;
    }
}

void foo_switch(char c)
{
    switch(c) {
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9': {
            printf("Was a number!\n");
            break;
        }
        case '{':
        case '[': {
            printf("Other stuff!\n");
            break;
        }
        default: break;
    }
}


const volatile char r = '5';

int main()
{
    foo_precheck(r);
    foo_switch(r);
}
```

This is the assembly generated for each function (clang -O2):

```
foo_precheck(char):                      # @foo_precheck(char)
        lea     eax, [rdi - 48]
        cmp     al, 10
        jae     .LBB0_2
        lea     rdi, [rip + .Lstr.4]
        jmp     puts@PLT                        # TAILCALL
.LBB0_2:
        movsx   eax, dil
        or      eax, 32
        cmp     eax, 123
        jne     .LBB0_5
        lea     rdi, [rip + .Lstr.3]
        jmp     puts@PLT                        # TAILCALL
.LBB0_5:
        ret
```

---

```
foo_switch(char):                        # @foo_switch(char)
        lea     eax, [rdi - 48]
        cmp     eax, 10
        jae     .LBB1_2
        lea     rdi, [rip + .Lstr.4]
        jmp     puts@PLT                        # TAILCALL
.LBB1_2:
        cmp     edi, 123
        je      .LBB1_4
        cmp     edi, 91
        jne     .LBB1_6
.LBB1_4:
        lea     rdi, [rip + .Lstr.3]
        jmp     puts@PLT                        # TAILCALL
.LBB1_6:
        ret
```

Can you make a general estimate which one is faster? I know it is architecture dependent, but the fact that it doesn't generate the same assembly made me curious if you make a general statement on what I should go for.

Comment: I'd use [`std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) and hope that they have optimized it properly. If you doubt which one is fastest, benchmark it.

Comment: I find them *extremely* similar (including no jumptable) with the only difference for `'['`. Is that a common use case which could be a bottleneck in the program?

Comment: @BoP Not as common as numbers I guess. It's for a json parser.

Comment: it's very rare that the performance of a single operation, executed once, matters. For something like JSON, you'd be parsing an entire document. You'd need to profile that case - the results are not simply the time of a single function multiplied by the length of the document.

Comment: @MSalters I know that, but I dare to assume that the faster function in this particular case will never be slower than the other one. Which means it would be the more sensible choice. How everything plays out in a bigger context is another question :)

Comment: Just looking at the (number of) assembly instructions is kind of half the story. For to actual performance other things come into play : How well do the instructions pipeline, How well will the branch predictor do and how good will the cache use be. In the end the only thing you can do is measure, and then measure again.

Comment: 1. yes this is architecture dependent and the performance outcome can change from an a recent AMD processor to a recent intel processor or likely from a old AMD processor (pre-Zen) to a newer one (post-Zen). Modern processors execute many instructions in parallel in an out-of-order way with a very large window and they pipeline instructions. They also fuse instruction and can predict branches (which is crazy). Thus, critical path, instruction latency, actual data and the quality of the prediction matters a lot more than the number of instruction. The thing is we are lacking information here.

Comment: 2. unpredictable/poorly-predicted branches are slow (because a long pipeline). Having more branch is generally a sign of a slower code, especially when they are dependent. Processors can track a limited number of branches for prediction so having more of them result in a higher risk for the prediction to fail because of too many branches. This is not the case here but this code is typically an incomplete example since the `puts` will be replace by code that will certainly contains conditions and so behave differently. Please benchmark complete code. Processors are more complex than you think.

Comment: 3. consider looking SimdJson which is a very highly optimized parser making use of SIMD instructions so to beat nearly all other implementations. Reading data byte per byte is not very efficient (but using SIMD instructions is far more complex, especially considering error handling and strict standards). Note that using SIMD instruction is not always faster for that it is not always a silverbullet.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you Jerome. I'm working on an embedded system which doesn't have SIMD instructions. I already had a look at SIMD json. I know about the branch predictor, but I still think for certain cases you can actually speculate if something is faster or slower based on the number of branches. I will probably do an extensive benchmarking with multiple architectures later, but I thought someone could put me on the right track :)

Comment: `if (c >= 0x30 && c <= 0x39)` -- don't do that. `if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')` or, even better, `if (std::is digit((unsigned char)c))`.

Comment: Embedded systems react generally very differently from maintream x86-64 processors. But AFAIK most embedded processors are ARM/RISC-V one nowadays (especially one without SIMD instructions) so it is certainly better to compile this to ARM/RISC-V asm. The kind of processor you target will typically execute instruction in-order (or possibly out-of-order with a very restricted execution and very small window). Prediction will be very basic if any, and the pipeline far smaller. This means the overhead are completely different from mainstream x86-64 processors.

Comment: Conditions are not much a problem on processors with a very small pipeline because they just need to wait for few cycle for them to be complete (instead of a dozen). The cost of missprediction (if any) is low. It makes branchless code less interesting but this is dependent of the latency/throughput of the branchless instructions. It is a tradeoff between the two that guide optims like this but such are dependent of the actual architecture. Experience often prove that micro-benchmarks give surprising results (even for skilled people). Architecture-independent optim is hard if even possible here

Comment: [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/Utfc7gnG-UzQ5-yCqOq86qgs8Bs) gives equivalent result for both (`printf` dropped).

Comment: @Jarod42 Compilers can inline the functions and perform a branchless optimization. In fact this is what Clang does (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/aPMjb4v58)). Moreover, the processor can easily see that the same branch is taken over and over so it can be much faster than in real-world cases. The branchless version is disadvantaged here. This is why such micro-benchmark are so hard: there is a lot of possible biased. Not to mention QuickBench is not precise enough for this: a [new run](https://quick-bench.com/q/irqrSR9nX1LVsEwAuC2O9RUaH_s) gives a 10% difference (this is just pure noise).